# Generate data from a bivariate power-law distribution in R

Tags: r, random-generation, bivariate, power-law

I need to generate data from a random vector that follows a bivariate power-law:
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{C}{XY} \left(\frac{X}{X_0} \right)^{-\alpha} \left(\frac{Y}{Y_0} \right)^{-\beta} ,
$$
where $X_0,Y_0,C>0$ are constants. I can generate data from a univariate power-law by using a uniform random variable and transform it (I am using $\texttt{R}$), but I have no idea how to do it for a random vector. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Comment: If $C\neq\alpha\beta$, then $f_{X,Y}$ is not a density function (since it doesn't integrate 1). $C=\alpha\beta$ is the only value that makes $f_{X,Y}$ a density function. This is easy to prove by integrating with respect to $x$ and $y$. If you want to use a copula to modelling the dependence between the marginals, then the expression for the density will be different. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

The bivariate density you are presenting is nothing but the product of two Pareto densities with parameters $(X_0,\alpha)$ and $(Y_0,\beta)$, respectively, and $C=\alpha\beta$. So, you can re-write it as follows:

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \left[\dfrac{\alpha}{X}\left(\dfrac{X}{X_0}\right)^{-\alpha}\right]\left[\dfrac{\beta}{Y}\left(\dfrac{Y}{Y_0}\right)^{-\beta}\right],$$

which implies that $X$ and $Y$ are independent Pareto random variables. Therefore, you can generate from the bivariate distribution by generating two independent univariate Pareto samples with the corresponding parameters:

```
library(actuar)

# Parameters
ns = 100
alpha = 1
beta = 2
X0 = 1
Y0 = 1

# Samples

Z = cbind(rpareto(n=ns, shape=alpha, scale=X0),rpareto(n=ns, shape=beta, scale=Y0))
```

Comment: Actually $C$ is a fixed constant. You can't choose its value, so we  don't have the pareto index. I computed the marginals and found that the variables are not independent, I'm thinking about using copulas to have the joint effect.

Comment: +1 This answer is correct. If you believe the variables are not independent, then your *question* is wrong, not this answer, because the question implies the variables *are* independent.